Can an analogy to functions be used to justify the preference for simple hypotheses?
In an interesting paper by Roger White, a philosopher, he argues that our assumption for simple hypotheses over complex ones shouldn’t be considered an assumption purely for aesthetic reasons but that one can actually construct an argument for this.
His argument begins by considering an analogy to a black box that contains a pointer and a dial. The dial has a finite number of possible positions that determine the pointer’s position which is also one of a finite number of values. A mathematical function can be used to represent how the dial positions lead to the pointer positions.
His goal then is to prove the following Simplicity Favouring Principle:
SFP: The greater the complexity of a function f, the less probable it is that the machine computes f.
He says,

There are two kinds of complexity to be distinguished here: the complexity of the inner workings of the machine, and the complexity of its outer behaviour: the complexity of the function that it computes. The complexity of the mechanism in the box is roughly a matter of how many different kinds of parts it contains, all of which are intricately linked so that a change in any part would make a major difference to the workings of the mechanism. The notion of complexity of a function is harder to characterize, but I will assume that we recognize it well enough when we see it. For instance a linear function is intuitively characterized as simple, and higher order polynomials as more complex.


The intuitive complexity of a function bears an important relation to the complexity of a mechanism: the more complex the function, the more complex the mechanism required to compute it. A simple mechanism consisting of just a rubber band connecting the dial and pointer could only compute a simple linear function; a more complex function like 7x^3 - 6x^2 + 2x + 1 can be computed only by a machine with very many different moving parts connected in an intricate way.

Now, the number of functions that a machine can compute increases rapidly with the number of parts in the machine and thus the complexity of the machine. The more moving parts, the more ways you can rearrange the machine.
This then follows that given a particular machine, the probability of us guessing the correct function produced by the machine gets lower and lower the more complex it is.
Thus, as long as one makes the more modest assumption (A) that a machine with greater complexity is not considerably more likely than a machine with lower (see addendum for more on this), it follows that a complex function is less likely to be true. This then gives us a rational reason to prefer simpler hypotheses given that they have a higher prior probability.
Is this analogy tenable? It seems awfully similar to Solomonoff’s theory of inductive inference but I’m not familiar with that theory as much, and perhaps someone more familiar can refer to any philosophical works arguing for simplicity using functions as an analogy (or criticizing it).

Addendum:
White’s commentary on assumption A:

(A) The machine is not considerably more likely to be complex than simple.
It is not obvious exactly which possible probability distributions over M1 - Mn (machines with different complexities) are rationally acceptable, so it might seem wise to remain entirely noncommittal. But this is not always an option. We may just be curious as to what the box will do next, or may be forced to act in ways whose outcome will depend on its behaviour. (We often need to make the best estimate we can as to how the world will behave.) So we are forced to distribute our credence in some way among the possible degrees of machine-complexity. From a position of ignorance about the contents of the box, a distribution that violates (A) would seem rather arbitrary and unreasonable. What could justify someone in having a much greater expectation that the box is chock full of intricately linked moving parts, than that it just contains one or two? In any event, (A) is a more modest assumption than that the mechanism is especially likely to be simple. Someone sceptical about our ability to judge a priori the degree of com- plexity of a black box’s contents might assign a roughly even initial credence over M1 - Mn. By the argument above, this would be more than enough to support SFP.


White's argument is mathematically funky, especially in his estimations of conditional probabilities and of dependence on priors, see Smith's rebuttal:"White requires assumptions for his arguments that are at least as controversial as the simplicity favoring principle he wishes to support."

@Conifold I managed to access that paper and he says, in reference to assumption (A), “But this is a questionable move. A proposition being arbitrary gives no positive support to its negation – at best it supports withholding judgment. But this is White’s very point: that you shouldn’t give support to any particular prior probability distribution, and that includes a distribution where complex machines are more likely. Elsewhere in the paper, Smith also says that assumption (A) might not even be needed to advance White’s argument, so if anything, the paper just makes his argument stronger.

Did you actually read the paper or only looked for parts that reinforce your pet conclusions? You can start by finishing reading the mentioned passages and proceed to notice that problems with (A) are on top of White's funny math. His use of (A) is  fallacious, and if it worked (A) would not be needed.

@Conifold Given the speed by which you responded, and without detailing any specific problems with White’s paper initially, one can also ask if you read the paper. Nevertheless, yes I did, and a lot of the other arguments just seem to come down to nitpicking over details. White never claimed to analyze complexity objectively, but rather give a basic outline of an analogy. For example, Smith uses the fact that standard trig functions are equivalent to infinite order polynomials as an argument to suggest complexity here is subjective. But a controversial example doesn’t disprove a trend

Hence his disclaimer at the end: So while the situation is not nearly so clear cut, the two factors which were crucial to the argument above appear to hold in ordinary cases: (i) the more complex the hypothesized regularity, the more complex the causal mechanism required to produce it, and (ii) the range of regularities which could be produced by a causal mechanism increases dramatically with the complexity of the mechanism.

It reminds me of the Enigma Machine. Yet, the complexity could be bypassed / broken with some knowledge and a small amount of encrypted text each day. Similar to other codes. One Time Pad requires only a pack of paper, but is unbreakable, even in theory. A potential implementation is with entangled particles, which would also cause it to transmit infinitely fast, that is, an Ansible.
